# SQL Server : how to make a column optional?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that searches for data, then inserts it into a table. I also want to sort and decide the order of insertion without creating duplicates. The column that I want to sort by should not be inserted but I do not know if its possible to make a column optional..

This is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Plans (personID, Title, CreatedOn) 
    SELECT DISTINCT
        P.personID,
        A.title,
        A.CreatedOn,
        P.AppointmentTime    -- I want to sort by this column
    ... Join conditions
    ... ORDER BY P.AppointmentTime DESC
```

The code works great my only question is can how somehow exclude the `P.AppointmentTime` column from the insert? Since I am using distinct, I have to have it in the select list. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: What happens when you simply remove that field from the select

Comment: Thats right, simply remove column name from select list,otherwise it will throw error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by`:

```
INSERT INTO Plans (personID, Title, CreatedOn) 
    Select distinct P.personID, A.title, A.CreatedOn
    from  ... Join conditions
    group by P.personID, A.title, A.CreatedOn
    order by max(P.AppointmentTime) desc
```